# Energy-momentum tensor from the variation of action of RNS strings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In exercise 4.6 p. 121 of Becker, Becker, Schwarz's book *'String theory and M-theory'*, they state that under using the variation $\delta_+X=a^+\partial_+X$ and $\delta_+\psi_A=a^+\partial_+\psi_A$ where $A=\pm$, we may identify the components of the energy momentum tensor of the RNS strings from the variation of the action $$\delta_+S=\frac{1}{\pi}\int d^2\sigma \: \delta_+\mathcal{L},$$ where
\begin{align}
\delta_+\mathcal{L}&=\delta_+(2\partial_+X\cdot\partial_-X+i\psi_-\cdot\partial_+\psi_-+i\psi_+\cdot\partial_-\psi_+)\\
&=a^+(-2\partial_-(\partial_+X\cdot\partial_+X)+i\partial_+(\psi_+\cdot\partial_-\psi_+)-i\partial_-(\psi_+\cdot\partial_+\psi_+))\\
&=-2a^+(\partial_-T_{++}+\partial_+T_{-+}),
\end{align}
and similarly using $\delta_-$. So my question is how did the authors go from the first line to the second one, because naively I would think that:
\begin{align}
\delta_+\mathcal{L}=&\delta_+(2\partial_+X\cdot\partial_-X+i\psi_-\cdot\partial_+\psi_-+i\psi_+\cdot\partial_-\psi_+)\\
=&2[\partial_+(\delta_+X)\cdot\partial_-X+\partial_+X\cdot\partial_-(\delta_+X)]+i[(\delta_+\psi_-)\cdot\partial_+\psi_-+\psi_-\cdot\partial_+(\delta_+\psi_-)]\\
&+i[(\delta_+\psi_+)\cdot\partial_-\psi_++\psi_+\cdot\partial_-(\delta_+\psi_+)]\\
=&a^+\partial_+(2\partial_+X\cdot\partial_-X+i\psi_-\cdot\partial_+\psi_-+i\psi_+\cdot\partial_-\psi_+).
\end{align}
Then I would find totally incorrect $T_{-+}$ and $T_{++}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just write the variation for Bosonic field, similar logic will follow for $\psi$.

Start with $2 nd $ line of your calculation and substitute the value of $\delta_+ X$. Expression will look like this
$$2 a^+  (\partial_-X) \partial_+ \partial_+ X + 2 a^+  (\partial_+X) \partial_- \partial_+ X $$
Do the integration by parts and throw away boundary terms. After integrating 
$$ -2 \partial_+(\partial_-X) \partial_+X -2 \partial_-(\partial_+X) \partial_+X
$$
Using the fact that $\partial_-\partial_+X= \partial_+\partial_-X$, and just take $\partial_-$ comman to full expression. Hence you will get the correct $T_{++}$.